# How to bring out the color in the box

Tags: html, canvas

What script error below?

```
var color = ["black","gray","silver","white","yellow","orange","red","brown","pink","purple","blue","aqua","green","lime","olive","navy","teal"];
for(a=0; a<color.length; a++){
    document.write("<li><a href='#' class='color' id='"+color[a]+"'></a></li>");
```

the problem, in a box does not appear the color.

How to bring out the color in the boxes?

Comment: _"bring out the color in the boxes?"_ - What do you mean?

Comment: colors in the box does not appear,

Comment: I don't know what box you are talking about, could you be more specific?

Comment: I want to make an application in the canvas , using this script but the colors do not appear in the box and its application can not draw

Comment: If you want to draw it on canvas, you can't append elements to DOM. You need to use canvas

Comment: I want to make an application in the canvas , using this script but the colors do not appear in the box and its application can not draw

Comment: I use this script , but can not bring up the color